# Cloudinary showing JSON error in production

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js, cloudinary, dev-to-production

I am using this cloudinary function in my nextjs project

```
import { v2 as cloudinary, UploadApiResponse } from 'cloudinary'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'

 dotenv.config()

const cloudinaryConfig = {
cloud_name: process.env.CloudName as string,
api_key: process.env.CloudapiKey as string,
api_secret: process.env.CloudapiSecret as string,
}

cloudinary.config(cloudinaryConfig)

export default async function uploadPDFtoCloud(
pdfFile: string,
): Promise<string> {
try {
const result: UploadApiResponse = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(
  pdfFile,
  {
    folder: 'file_doc_pdf',
    resource_type: 'raw',
    type: 'authenticated',
  },
)
return result.secure_url as string
} catch (error) {
 console.error('Error Uploading file:', error)
 throw new Error('Failed to upload PDF: ')
}
}
```

The problem is that this function is working in development normally and returning secure url but while running npm run build to test in production I encountered

```
Error Uploading file: {
message: `Server return invalid JSON response. Status Code 500. SyntaxError: Unexpected token 
'<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON`,     
name: 'Error',
http_code: 500
```

While build is still running and each time I test the function when I run the app, I get the same error ,I checked the env variables as all are coming right but after some testing the error is triggering at this code line

```
const result: UploadApiResponse = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(
  pdfFile,
  {
    folder: 'file_doc_pdf',
    resource_type: 'raw',
    type: 'authenticated',
  },
)
```

So what might be the problem that causing this error in production and why not in development!?

Answer (score 0):

You should (in your case), upload the file as binary:

```
//modify code below if needed 
const pdfFile = req.file.buffer.toString('base64');
console.log('pdfFile: ', pdfFile)
```

You have the error `500` because the server can't handle your pdf. The problem is not cloudinary, the problem is actually how you get pdf file. Other part of your code seems to be ok.

```
   //mostly probably, you need to indicate base64 type of file 
   cloudinary.uploader.upload(`data:${req.file.mimetype};base64,${pdfFile}`{
            folder: 'file_doc_pdf',
            resource_type: 'raw',
            type: 'authenticated',
   },
```

P.S. In any case, `console.log()` you error to see the details
P.S 2 : error in production very often relies to .env variables or CORS policy.

Answer (score 0):

Using the cloudinary widget
https://next.cloudinary.dev/cldvideoplayer/basic-usage

now I can upload images in production (npm run build) also:

```
'use client';
import { CldUploadWidget } from 'next-cloudinary';
import { typeSecureUrl } from '../lib/types';
import toast from 'react-hot-toast';

const CloudinaryWidget = ({
  setSecureUrl,
  setPublicid
}: typeSecureUrl) => {
  return (
    <div className='mb-4'>
      {/* // <CldUploadWidget uploadPreset='myuploadpreset'> */}
      <CldUploadWidget
        signatureEndpoint='/pages/api/sign-image'
        options={{
          sources: ['local', 'url', 'unsplash'],
          multiple: false,
          maxFiles: 1,
          tags: ['post'],
          folder: 'posts',
          cropping: true,
          showSkipCropButton: true,
          maxImageFileSize: 100000, // 100K
          maxImageWidth: 800,
          showPoweredBy: false,
          showCompletedButton: true
        }}
        onSuccess={(result: any, { widget }) => {
          if (!result.info) return;

          if (result.event === 'success') {
            // console.log(result.info?.public_id!);
            // console.log(result.info.secure_url!);
            setSecureUrl(result.info.secure_url);
            setPublicid(result.info.public_id);
            toast.success('Immagine scaricata' + result.info?.public_id!);
          } else {
            toast.error('Immagine non scaricata');
          }
          widget.close();
        }}
      >
        {({ open }) => {
          return (
            <>
              <label
                className='mb-2 block text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white'
                htmlFor='file_input'
              >
                Scarica Immagine
              </label>
              <button className='btn btn-primary' onClick={() => open()}>
                Upload
              </button>
            </>
          );
        }}
      </CldUploadWidget>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CloudinaryWidget;
```